# sql | Проблемы с русским языком

Tags: php, mysql, sql

В базе данных русский текст отображается нормально, но когда вывожу ассоциативный массив, то получается что-то типо С‚РѕР СЃРєР°Рј.

Comment: Это UTF8, который попытались отобразить как CP1251. Проблема - не на сервере БД и не в соединении с БД, а в используемой кодировке средства отображения при выводе на экран. Именно отображения на экране - в переменных скрипта всё правильно. Например, браузер пытается отобразить страницу с UTF-фрагментами текста, тогда как заголовки утверждают, что передан код страницы в 1251.

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, Ваш код, чтобы можно было дать верный ответ, решающий Вашу проблему.

Answer (score 1):

Причина в разнице кодировки MySQL и скрипта. Вариантов 2:

1. Сделать одинаковую кодировку скриптовых файлов (в заголовке тоже) и БД
2. Постоянно конвертировать либо при записи в БД либо при выводе в скрипте

Answer (score -1):

Как было сказано коллегами, причина проблемы в разных кодировках БД и соединения с ней. Сразу после подключения к БД до запроса каких-либо данных выполните запрос

```
set character set 'utf8';
```

Этот запрос настроит подключение к БД на работу с UTF-8, которая является внутренней кодировкой строк PHP, и заставит MySQL автоматически конвертировать данные из кодировки, в которой они хранятся, в UTF-8. Это должно решить Вашу проблему.

Comment: Судя по показанным "кривым" символам - происходит всё с точностью до наоборот. И подключение уже работает в UTF8.

Comment: Помогло, спасибо Igor Dyshlenko

Comment: Если помогло - отметьте ответ как принятый. А то я и так 2 пунктов репутации лишился благодаря @Akina. ;)